# Why cannot play this video

Tags: android, video-streaming

My app use a VideoView to play video URL. Most video URLs can be played correctly, except some. All those video cannot played correctly by my android app CAN be played correctly by iOS.

All videos in my app are directly played with URL, not local file. When test the video with system default video player, I am also using URL, not local file.

Among those videos cannot play, there are two results:
Result case 1, the video completely cannot play; it is always loading. The video can trigger onPrepared() event, but getDuration() returns zero. When play these video with system default video player, system player also always loading and cannot play. Here is the video info got from MediaInfo.app after download it to my Mac:

```
General
Complete name                            : /Users/aaaaa/Downloads/movie.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : QuickTime
Codec ID                                 : qt  
File size                                : 549 KiB
Duration                                 : 10s 0ms
Overall bit rate                         : 449 Kbps
Encoded date                             : UTC 2014-12-04 22:48:13
Tagged date                              : UTC 2014-12-04 22:48:14
Writing library                          : Apple QuickTime

Video
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 2 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 10s 0ms
Bit rate                                 : 194 Kbps
Width                                    : 640 pixels
Height                                   : 640 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.000
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 0.400 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 1.182
Stream size                              : 236 KiB (43%)
Title                                    : Core Media Video
Encoded date                             : UTC 2014-12-04 22:48:13
Tagged date                              : UTC 2014-12-04 22:48:14
Color range                              : Limited

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 10s 0ms
Source duration                          : 10s 54ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 256 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 308 KiB (56%)
Source stream size                       : 309 KiB (56%)
Title                                    : Core Media Audio
Encoded date                             : UTC 2014-12-04 22:48:13
Tagged date                              : UTC 2014-12-04 22:48:14
```

Result case 2: when play the video, sound is playing, but screen is always black. On Note3, when drag the media controller progress bar, the screen becomes normal; but on S5, drag progress bar does not work. When play with system default player, same result. The MediaInfo:

```
General
Complete name                            : /Users/aaaaa/Downloads/44466705691c6b34e9ea2038ca5a6d4f031946.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 483 KiB
Duration                                 : 23s 749ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 167 Kbps
Encoded date                             : UTC 2014-12-07 03:19:38
Tagged date                              : UTC 2014-12-07 03:19:38
Writing application                      : Lavf54.6.100

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3.0
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 2 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 23s 625ms
Bit rate                                 : 139 Kbps
Width                                    : 480 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.000
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 0.550 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 1.095
Stream size                              : 400 KiB (83%)
Encoded date                             : UTC 2014-12-07 03:19:38
Tagged date                              : UTC 2014-12-07 03:19:38
Color primaries                          : BT.601 NTSC
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.601
Color range                              : Limited

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 23s 749ms
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 27.5 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 32.0 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel(s)_Original                      : 1 channel
Channel positions                        : Front: C
Sampling rate                            : 16.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 79.7 KiB (17%)
Encoded date                             : UTC 2014-12-07 03:19:38
Tagged date                              : UTC 2014-12-07 03:19:38
```

Above two videos have very low frame rate.

Why these two video cannot play by android VideoView? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post any error log or code snippet for the same?